# Spring Netflix Zuul: Authenticate and Route the same request

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-session, netflix-zuul

I have a bunch of services that sit behind a Zuul Edge Server. The Zuul Edge Server also performs authentication. The session is shared with all services using Spring Session. I want to be able to authenticate and route the request to a service in the same flow. I looked at [Dave Syer's tutorial](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/double) where a Gateway Server can authenticate and route requests.

On that project, the following commands work:

- `curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:8080/user`
- `curl -c cookie.txt -u admin:admin http://localhost:8080/user 
  && curl -b cookie.txt http://localhost:8080/admin/user`

I was expecting this to work as well but it doesn't:

- `curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:8080/admin/user`

I was expecting the Gateway server to authenticate, create a redis session, route the request to admin service which would have picked the Authentication from redis session. The request is being routed to admin service, but it also attempts a Basic Authentication and fails.

This is what I see in admin service's logs:

```
o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'admin'
o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : User 'admin' not found
o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Authentication request for failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
```

I get an HTTP 401 Unauthorized response.

I also tried to disable HTTP Basic Authentication in admin service, but then I get HTTP 403 Forbidden response.

Is there some way to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I think this can't work due to the way Spring Session is implemented to save session. I'm waiting for a response to my [question](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/202) on github.

Comment: Does `admin/user` url pattern pass through spring-security filters in gateway without authentication? Is it configured to commence authentication ?

Comment: @AhamedMustafaM No, it can't. It's protected by Basic Auth.

Comment: I'm developing very similar architecture. It would be nice if the first call could authenticate and access a service via zuul. Currently I've just put a 'login' endpoint on mu zuul service that does not require a trip to another service. It is still an uneccesary step, but it at least makes logical sense for clients trying to access the api.

Comment: I think solution was already implemented in `spring-session` version 1.1.0. More info in another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751700/spring-zuul-api-gateway-with-spring-session-redis-authenticate-and-route-in-sa?rq=1#answer-38867506